# Angular 5 Add Token to header before posting with httpClient

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using a restapi and it requires that I add a token to the header before I can create a new record.

Right now I have a service to create a new record which looks like this:

service.ts

```
create(title, text) {
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', token); // Not added yet as this is the reason for the question
    return this.http.post('http://myapi/api.php/posts', {
      title: 'added title',
      text: 'added text'
    }, { headers });
  }
```

app.component.ts

```
add() {
    this.service.create('my title', 'body text').subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
```

The problem with this is that it won't let me add the new record because it requires a token and in order to get a token I need to run this:

```
getToken() {
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    return this.http.post('http://myapi/api.php/user', {
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'password'
    }, { headers });
  }
```

My question is...How do I get this two together into one call instead of two...or when is the best way to do this?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49903613/4399281

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from what @Pardeep Jain already mentioned, you can add an interceptor (> Angular version 4, you mentioned you're using 5) for your HttpClient that will automatically add Authorization headers for all requests.

If you need top be authenticated for only one request, it's better to keep things simple and use Pardeep's solution.

If you want to be authenticated for most of your requests, then add an interceptor.

module, let's say `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
 //...
 providers: [
    //...
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: JwtInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    //...
    ]
//...
})
```

and your jwt interceptor, let's say `jwt.interceptor.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private injector: Injector, private router: Router) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {  
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', /* here you fetch your jwt */this.getToken())
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    }); 
    return next.handle(authReq).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // do stuff with response if you want
      }
    }, (response: HttpErrorResponse) => { });
  }

  getToken() {
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    return this.http.post('http://myapi/api.php/user', {
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'password'
    }, { headers });
  }
}
```

If you want to read something, more here: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: well explained answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The code should be like this -

```
create(title, text) {
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    headers.append('Authorization', token);
    return this.http.post('http://myapi/api.php/posts', {
      title: 'added title',
      text: 'added text'
    }, { headers });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is...How do I get this two together into one call instead
>   of two...or when is the best way to do this?

You should not.
Authentication is one thing that should be performed a single time for the client or as the authentication ticket has expired.
Posting some content is another thing that you should not mix with authentication.

So authenticate the client once and store the ticket.
Then pass the ticket in the header for any request to a secured endpoints/methods.  Or use a transverse way as an interceptor to set it in the send requests if you don't want to repeat the code.

Comment: ...and to store the token/ticket, you could use localstorage, sessionstorage or cookies, etc.. And, fetch token values from there directly.. if token expire, refresh token and update the storage too.