# how to handle API token in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to handle request - response with token in API how can i handle it ?
Please give any example of API token demo & Login auth. because i am new in angular.
Ex:
    const authToken = this.authService.getToken();

Comment: take a look [here](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example) for a tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 HttpInterceptor and sending Authorization Token in header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903185/angular-5-httpinterceptor-and-sending-authorization-token-in-header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an HTTP Interceptor to intercept requests and add the auth token if it exists. You can also redirect to a login page if the auth token doesn't exist.

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headers = httpReq.headers;
    headers.set('Authorization', this.authService.getToken());

    const newRequest = request.clone({headers: headers});

    return next.handle(newRequest);
  }
}
```

Ensure you add your interceptor to your module

```
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service.ts';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './interceptors/auth.interceptor.ts';

providers: [
  AuthService,
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
];
```